# Render partial view in mvc using jquery ajax fails

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I'm new at jquery ajax programming and I have a problem. I have a hyperlink text which could be clikced to order a product. I want this link to be clicked and a partial view is rendered using jquery ajax. I can't get it work and I don't know why. Hope somebody will help.

This is my html action link. So I'm looping through a list of products. When the user presses the link, a productID and a tableID is sent tot controller.

View is rendered inside a div:

```
<div id='divResult'>
    @Html.Action("TableTransactions", new { tableID = 2 });
</div>

@Html.ActionLink(item.Omschrijving,"Orders","Tables",
new { tableID = Request.Params["tableID"]), productID = item.ProductID },
            new { @class = "UpdateTransactionLink" });
```

This is the controller method:

```
public ActionResult TableTransactions(int? tableID, int? productID)
{
 return PartialView(transactionBL.TransactionList(tableID.Value));  
}
```

This is the ajax jquery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.UpdateTransactionLink').click(function () {
            alert("Clicked via ajax");

            $.ajax({
                url: "/Tables/TableTransactions",
                datatype: "text",
                type: "POST",
                success: function (data) {
                    $('#divResult').html(data);
                },
                error: function () {
                    $("#divResult").html("ERROR");
                }
            });


        });
    });    

</script>
```

But when I click on the link the tableID and the productID are still null and it fires twice.

Can anybody help me out?

Comment: It fires twice because its an link so your doing both an ajax call and a normal redirect - you need to cancel the default action. And in the ajax call you do not pass any data to the method so the parameters are `null`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using post but you are not passing the data in request, You can use data parameter of the $.ajax for the same, or you can use the below code where data is part of url. Also please return false from click event to prevent default href of link.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.UpdateTransactionLink').click(function () {
        alert("Clicked via ajax");

        $.ajax({
            url: $(this).attr("href"), // used data from url
            datatype: "text",
            type: "POST",
            success: function (data) {
                $('#divResult').html(data);
            },
            error: function () {
                $("#divResult").html("ERROR");
            }
        });
        return false;

    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for all of your answers appreciate the help you provided.  But eventually is the answer of Dinesh what solved my problem. The data is passed to the controller method in the request by using the data from the url. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your ajax call, you should set parameter values in ajax so they posted with Ajax. Some other parameters are missing i completed your ajax call please try and tell me.

Please use some button or other element to handle static link no need to use ActionLink when you are interested in Ajax call

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.UpdateTransactionLink').click(function (e) {
            alert("Clicked via ajax");
e.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
                url: "/Tables/TableTransactions",
                type: "POST",
                data: { tableID: 1,productID=4 //set values accordingly },
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"
                datatype: "html", //Should be html
                success: function (data) {
                    $('#divResult').html(data);
                },
                error: function () {
                    $("#divResult").html("ERROR");
                }
            });


        });
    });    

</script>
```